# addComponentAsRefTo error when using component from storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have made a project with storybook, where I have added some components.
When I try to use these components in another project I get an error

> Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded.

I build the storybook as

```
"build": "babel components --out-dir dist-es6 --source-maps inline",
```

my .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
"presets": [
  "es2015",  // whichever presets your projects use should match here
  "stage-0",
  "react"
],
"plugins": [
  "transform-runtime", // for polyfills
  "transform-react-remove-prop-types" // we use this to remove the propTypes
]}
```

I export my component with an index.js file like this:

```
export { default as DateFilter } from './DateFilter';
```

I include the component:

```
import { DateFilter } from 'storybook/dist-es6';
```

I do a nmp link in the storybook in order to use it in my project. I can see the component, but it fails with the uncaught error.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a problem with storybook and nwb in combination.
Both storybook and my project used react, so I needed to ignore the react used by storybook.

This was added to the nwb.config.js file

```
aliases: {
   react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
   'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom'),
   'prop-types': path.resolve('./node_modules/prop-types')
 },
```

In the end I actually removed nwb :)